# AJAX file uploader for image preview

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery AJAX file uploader for uploading to tmp directory and doing an image preview. This is working fine but I now have trouble uploading the actual image file when the actual form is submitted. It seems like whenever AJAX uploader is triggered by change event, it takes the file object from the file type input element and submits to hidden iframe form. Is there a way we can leave the file object without removing it even after the image preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this issue. What I have done is to upload the actual uploaded file (via hidden iframe which was created by AJAX onchange event) to the temp folder with unique filename then appending this filename into hidden field inside the original form then use this value in hidden field when user submits the form to retrieve the file in temp folder copy to main image folder, rename it then delete the old one using unlink() php function!

Whew! So much work for such a simple method. I hope IE and Safari support FileReader object! (I hate ActiveX!)